# Client side report generator

Tags: javascript, html, report

I need a report system for Microsoft sharepoint online. Therefore, I cannot use WCF services and I do not have full ASP.Net support. All that I have is HTML5 and javascript. And Silverlight, of course, but without support mobile device.

Please suggest me a product that can build reports on client side.

Answer (score 0):

I think that [knockoutjs](http://knockoutjs.com/) + [SPServices](http://spservices.codeplex.com/) is the best approach.

You can learn how to combine them [here](https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/devwiki/articles/pages/sharepoint-development-using-headjs-knockoutjs-and-spservices.aspx).

Knockoutjs is library/framework which implements MVVM pattern, SPServices makes life easier when you try to get SharePoint data in javascript.

Comment: Thank you, Greg. But this is not exactly report generator.